# Custom Cell - UITableView does not load properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I have made a custom cell with one image and one lable..The problem is that when the app starts, the table appears as shown below:

[image]

but when i scroll down and scroll up again it appears how it is meant to be..i.e i want it to load in the way shown below

[image]

Dont know what is causing this problem and wht can be the solution for this..pls help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set heightForRow method correctly?

Comment: Set the cell height of your cell and cellheight of your tableview to same. Check the autolayout also

Comment: @NickCatib After reading ur comment i added ` func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 235
    }` and my app now crashes with CoreData error. :(

Comment: @MidhunMP.. yes that was the issue.. my cell height and Row height were different.. thanks a ton.. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be, the problem lies here. Have a look once.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   return 80;
  }
```

Comment: my cell height and Row height were different... problem solved.. thanks.

Comment: If this solved your problem, up vote the answer or tick the right mark . Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It look's like the content view of the next cell in table view is getting above the first cell. Try setting

```
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

which will clip the content view of each cell within it's frame.

Comment: i dont want to clip the contents.. anyways, my cell height and Row height were different... problem solved.. thanks.